# How do I display a subset of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe `df` that contains datetimes for every hour of a day between 2003-02-12 to 2017-06-30 and I want to delete all datetimes between 24th Dec and 1st Jan of EVERY year.
An extract of my data frame is:

```
...
7505,2003-12-23 17:00:00
7506,2003-12-23 18:00:00
7507,2003-12-23 19:00:00
7508,2003-12-23 20:00:00
7509,2003-12-23 21:00:00
7510,2003-12-23 22:00:00
7511,2003-12-23 23:00:00
7512,2003-12-24 00:00:00
7513,2003-12-24 01:00:00
7514,2003-12-24 02:00:00
7515,2003-12-24 03:00:00
7516,2003-12-24 04:00:00
7517,2003-12-24 05:00:00
7518,2003-12-24 06:00:00
...
7723,2004-01-01 19:00:00
7724,2004-01-01 20:00:00
7725,2004-01-01 21:00:00
7726,2004-01-01 22:00:00
7727,2004-01-01 23:00:00
7728,2004-01-02 00:00:00
7729,2004-01-02 01:00:00
7730,2004-01-02 02:00:00
7731,2004-01-02 03:00:00
7732,2004-01-02 04:00:00
7733,2004-01-02 05:00:00
7734,2004-01-02 06:00:00
7735,2004-01-02 07:00:00
...
```

and my expected output is:

```
...
7505,2003-12-23 17:00:00
7506,2003-12-23 18:00:00
7507,2003-12-23 19:00:00
7508,2003-12-23 20:00:00
7509,2003-12-23 21:00:00
7510,2003-12-23 22:00:00
7511,2003-12-23 23:00:00
...
7728,2004-01-02 00:00:00
7729,2004-01-02 01:00:00
7730,2004-01-02 02:00:00
7731,2004-01-02 03:00:00
7732,2004-01-02 04:00:00
7733,2004-01-02 05:00:00
7734,2004-01-02 06:00:00
7735,2004-01-02 07:00:00
...
```

Comment: So you have a dataframe already, so assuming you are beyond importing that from the csv.  Can you better explain what your expected output is doing?  We don't know quite where you are trying to go.

Comment: I think you are probably looking for `date_range` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

Comment: @AeroBlue: the problem is not with *generating* the data, it is about *filtering* the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample dataframe:

```
                dates
0 2003-12-23 23:00:00
1 2003-12-24 05:00:00
2 2004-12-27 05:00:00
3 2003-12-13 23:00:00
4 2002-12-23 23:00:00
5 2004-01-01 05:00:00
6 2014-12-24 05:00:00
```

---

## Solution:

If you want it for every year between the following dates excluded, then extract the month and dates first:

```
df['month'] = df['dates'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['dates'].dt.day
```

And now put the condition check:

```
dec_days = [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]  
## if the month is dec, then check for these dates 
## if the month is jan, then just check for the day to be 1 like below
df = df[~(((df.month == 12) & (df.day.isin(dec_days))) | ((df.month == 1) & (df.day == 1)))]
```

Sample output:

```
                dates  month  day
0 2003-12-23 23:00:00     12   23
3 2003-12-13 23:00:00     12   13
4 2002-12-23 23:00:00     12   23
```

Answer (score 1):

This takes advantage of the fact that datetime-strings in the form `mm-dd` are sortable. Read everything in from the CSV file then filter for the dates you want:

```
df = pd.read_csv('...', parse_dates=['DateTime'])

s = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
excluded = (s == '01-01') | (s >= '12-24') # Jan 1 or >= Dec 24
df[~excluded]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` and boolean filtering with [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

```
# version 0.23.4
import pandas as pd

# make df
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('20181223', '20190103', freq='H'), columns=['date'])

# string format the date to only include the month and day
# then set it strictly less than '12-24' AND greater than or equal to `01-02`
df = df.loc[
    (df.date.dt.strftime('%m-%d') < '12-24') &
    (df.date.dt.strftime('%m-%d') >= '01-02')
].copy()

print(df)

                   date
0   2018-12-23 00:00:00
1   2018-12-23 01:00:00
2   2018-12-23 02:00:00
3   2018-12-23 03:00:00
4   2018-12-23 04:00:00
5   2018-12-23 05:00:00
6   2018-12-23 06:00:00
7   2018-12-23 07:00:00
8   2018-12-23 08:00:00
9   2018-12-23 09:00:00
10  2018-12-23 10:00:00
11  2018-12-23 11:00:00
12  2018-12-23 12:00:00
13  2018-12-23 13:00:00
14  2018-12-23 14:00:00
15  2018-12-23 15:00:00
16  2018-12-23 16:00:00
17  2018-12-23 17:00:00
18  2018-12-23 18:00:00
19  2018-12-23 19:00:00
20  2018-12-23 20:00:00
21  2018-12-23 21:00:00
22  2018-12-23 22:00:00
23  2018-12-23 23:00:00
240 2019-01-02 00:00:00
241 2019-01-02 01:00:00
242 2019-01-02 02:00:00
243 2019-01-02 03:00:00
244 2019-01-02 04:00:00
245 2019-01-02 05:00:00
246 2019-01-02 06:00:00
247 2019-01-02 07:00:00
248 2019-01-02 08:00:00
249 2019-01-02 09:00:00
250 2019-01-02 10:00:00
251 2019-01-02 11:00:00
252 2019-01-02 12:00:00
253 2019-01-02 13:00:00
254 2019-01-02 14:00:00
255 2019-01-02 15:00:00
256 2019-01-02 16:00:00
257 2019-01-02 17:00:00
258 2019-01-02 18:00:00
259 2019-01-02 19:00:00
260 2019-01-02 20:00:00
261 2019-01-02 21:00:00
262 2019-01-02 22:00:00
263 2019-01-02 23:00:00
264 2019-01-03 00:00:00
```

This will work with multiple years because we are only filtering on the month and day.

```
# change range to include 2017
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('20171223', '20190103', freq='H'), columns=['date'])

df = df.loc[
    (df.date.dt.strftime('%m-%d') < '12-24') &
    (df.date.dt.strftime('%m-%d') >= '01-02')
].copy()

print(df)

                    date
0    2017-12-23 00:00:00
1    2017-12-23 01:00:00
2    2017-12-23 02:00:00
3    2017-12-23 03:00:00
4    2017-12-23 04:00:00
5    2017-12-23 05:00:00
6    2017-12-23 06:00:00
7    2017-12-23 07:00:00
8    2017-12-23 08:00:00
9    2017-12-23 09:00:00
10   2017-12-23 10:00:00
11   2017-12-23 11:00:00
12   2017-12-23 12:00:00
13   2017-12-23 13:00:00
14   2017-12-23 14:00:00
15   2017-12-23 15:00:00
16   2017-12-23 16:00:00
17   2017-12-23 17:00:00
18   2017-12-23 18:00:00
19   2017-12-23 19:00:00
20   2017-12-23 20:00:00
21   2017-12-23 21:00:00
22   2017-12-23 22:00:00
23   2017-12-23 23:00:00
240  2018-01-02 00:00:00
241  2018-01-02 01:00:00
242  2018-01-02 02:00:00
243  2018-01-02 03:00:00
244  2018-01-02 04:00:00
245  2018-01-02 05:00:00
...                  ...
8779 2018-12-23 19:00:00
8780 2018-12-23 20:00:00
8781 2018-12-23 21:00:00
8782 2018-12-23 22:00:00
8783 2018-12-23 23:00:00
9000 2019-01-02 00:00:00
9001 2019-01-02 01:00:00
9002 2019-01-02 02:00:00
9003 2019-01-02 03:00:00
9004 2019-01-02 04:00:00
9005 2019-01-02 05:00:00
9006 2019-01-02 06:00:00
9007 2019-01-02 07:00:00
9008 2019-01-02 08:00:00
9009 2019-01-02 09:00:00
9010 2019-01-02 10:00:00
9011 2019-01-02 11:00:00
9012 2019-01-02 12:00:00
9013 2019-01-02 13:00:00
9014 2019-01-02 14:00:00
9015 2019-01-02 15:00:00
9016 2019-01-02 16:00:00
9017 2019-01-02 17:00:00
9018 2019-01-02 18:00:00
9019 2019-01-02 19:00:00
9020 2019-01-02 20:00:00
9021 2019-01-02 21:00:00
9022 2019-01-02 22:00:00
9023 2019-01-02 23:00:00
9024 2019-01-03 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try dropping on conditionals. Maybe with a pattern match to the date string or parsing the date as a number (like in Java) and conditionally removing.

```
datesIdontLike = df[df['colname'] == <stringPattern>].index
newDF = df.drop(datesIdontLike, inplace=True)
```

Check this out: https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-how-to-drop-rows-in-dataframe-by-conditions-on-column-values/

(If you have issues, let me know.)

Answer (score -1):

Since you want this to happen for every year, we can first define a series that where we replace the year by a static value (`2000` for example). Let `date` be the column that stores the date, we can generate such column as:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime({'year': 2000, 'month': df['date'].dt.month, 'day': df['date'].dt.day})
```

For the given sample data, we get:

```
>>> dt
0    2000-12-23
1    2000-12-23
2    2000-12-23
3    2000-12-23
4    2000-12-23
5    2000-12-23
6    2000-12-23
7    2000-12-24
8    2000-12-24
9    2000-12-24
10   2000-12-24
11   2000-12-24
12   2000-12-24
13   2000-12-24
14   2000-01-01
15   2000-01-01
16   2000-01-01
17   2000-01-01
18   2000-01-01
19   2000-01-02
20   2000-01-02
21   2000-01-02
22   2000-01-02
23   2000-01-02
24   2000-01-02
25   2000-01-02
26   2000-01-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Next we can filter the rows, like:

```
from datetime import date

df[(dt >= date(2000,1,2)) & (dt < date(2000,12,24))]
```

This gives us the following data for your sample data:

```
>>> df[(dt >= date(2000,1,2)) & (dt < date(2000,12,24))]
      id                  dt
0   7505 2003-12-23 17:00:00
1   7506 2003-12-23 18:00:00
2   7507 2003-12-23 19:00:00
3   7508 2003-12-23 20:00:00
4   7509 2003-12-23 21:00:00
5   7510 2003-12-23 22:00:00
6   7511 2003-12-23 23:00:00
19  7728 2004-01-02 00:00:00
20  7729 2004-01-02 01:00:00
21  7730 2004-01-02 02:00:00
22  7731 2004-01-02 03:00:00
23  7732 2004-01-02 04:00:00
24  7733 2004-01-02 05:00:00
25  7734 2004-01-02 06:00:00
26  7735 2004-01-02 07:00:00
```

So regardless what the year is, we will only consider dates between the 2<sup>nd</sup> of January and the 23<sup>rd</sup> of December (both inclusive).